Does "dial up" mainly mean authenticating oneself to ISP now?
I am studying CCNA online, and when I am studying the WAN and PPPOE part, the course instructor mentioned "dial up". I found many learning materials / support documents (like the Cisco one) also use the word "dial up". Sometimes, my colleague also use "dial up".
I am confused with the exact meaning of that word. I guess they mean connecting to the ISP in the context.
If I google, most of results will show something like Dial-up Internet access, which is an outdated technology, and today many of us are using FTTx.
Is the terminology something like BIOS and UEFI, which in turn, dial up is a custom way of speaking connecting to ISP in today.

In Cisco lingo, it's just a "Dialer" interface. 'tho it's no longer "dialing" anything. Not to be confused with cellular - which does need to specify what to connect to.

Yes, "dial up" terminology is largely outdated. Originally, it referred to dialing a telephone line (POTS or ISDN) for the physical layer and then authenticating via PPP for the data link layer. PPPoE is still common for authenticating to an ISP, so the similarity is there to keep using "dial up" (in contrast to just using an 'always-on' handover port on a CPE). The term is still alive with the popular RADIUS Remote Authentication Dial-In User Service as well.
